# Embeding a youtube video in layer in storyline 3 - how to stop the video?

Tags: video, youtube, articulate-storyline

We are using Articualte Storyline 3, and have an issue with embeded youtube video on a layer.
Let me Explain, I have embed a youtube video us embed code in a slide layer, when I open up that layer and starts the video and then close it before video come to an end, slide hides but video sound doesnt stop.

Comment: If you are going to post a question and then answer it, that's ok. Don't do it if you don't have any code to demonstrate your point read on [mcve].

Comment: yes sir, I have demonstrated it. Articulate storyline is tool, so if any one is working on it, he will find my provided solution helping them.

Comment: Ok...what have you demonstrated? This forum requires that you have code that you need help in fixing, which requires the poster (i.e. you) to post the code in a [mcve]. If you're just posting a question and answer for the benefit of others, include some code. If no code is required when using this tool, then you are in the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I have found to this issue is:
Use lightbox slide and trigger. whenever you close lightbox, video will stop, and you will never hear its sound in background even.